# iOS 9, Swift 2, xCode 7, Couldn't Compile Connection

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

Hey so my project was working fine and then I made some more view controllers and stuff and grouped some files and then this is the error I receive when I attempt to run it.

[image: The error i receive]

Comment: I do have a lot of segues and page changing so I don't know what exactly is happening.

Comment: It looks like you have messed something up in your storyboard. If you have version control and/or backup then rollback and make the changes again.  If not, why not?  and you will need to try and fix the broken - it looks like something to do with a segue from a table